# What are the benefits of either memcache or memcached with highly changed website?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, memcached

I read about memcache, But i did not find the answer about what are the benefits can i get from memcache with highly changed website ??

if the website publish the users posts as "facebook or twitter" what is the benefits when using the caching system in this case ??

Answer (score 0):

Memcached, lets you storage information in ram (with expiration timeout), a general approach will be: When a user need access to an frecuently object, first check if it's in memcached, if yes return it, if not, query database and get it, save to memcached (you can specify how long) and return.

The next time, you frecuently object will be available from memcached and you not need to query database.

You will decide what frecuently object will be cached.

Like:

- Frecuently twitt
- Profile page
- Pages